# Is there an option to tell bazel test not to cache output

Tags: testing, bazel

I have a long-running test which i want to monitor while it goes, but bazel caches all output and dumps it only in the end. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 4):

You can stream the test's output to stdout:

```
bazel test --test_output=streamed //foo:bar
```

The drawback is, Bazel runs all tests serially in this case.

Comment: Is there similar option for bazel build?